# Css buttons: Zooming is placing them wrong

Tags: html, css

I have a site, on the index page I have 5 buttons around a picture.

Without zoom everything looks like I want but when I zoom they get misplaced directly. I tried to use relative units instead of absolute ones but then it got worse.

My code:

```
.myButton4 {
    position:absolute;
    transition: .5s ease;
     top: 25%;
    left: 63%;
    background-color:#B28F00;
    -moz-border-radius:36px;
    -webkit-border-radius:36px;
    border-radius:36px;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Times New Roman;
    font-size:19px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:16px 34px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 0px #82797f;
    }
    .myButton4:hover {
        background-color:#B28F00;
    }
    .myButton4:active {
        position:relative;
        top:1px;
```

Maybe someone can help me? Someone asked for the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="'css.css"/>
        <title>title</title>
    </head>
    <body><center>
        <h1>Välkommen till min sida</h1></center></br></br>
        <center>
        <img src="indexpic.jpg" width="460" height="580"></center>
        <a href="http://link" class="myButton1"> text</a>
            <a href="http://link" class="myButton2">TEXT</a>
    </body>
```

Comment: Positioning is a poor and somewhat inflexible layout method. There are much better methods available to you. [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: can you share entire html?

Comment: Absloutly 
Have edit text